Number of paths in a grid going up and/or down
What is the number of different paths going from point $T_{i}$ to point $T_{o}$ through point $Z$. The only possible moves are upwards $(\uparrow)$, downwards $(\downarrow)$ or to the right $(\rightarrow)$, and can't go to the same point more than once.

I've tried going into cases (number of downwards movements from $Z$ to $T_{o}$ for example), but got stuck. Any help on what to do on this kind of problems? With only moves up/right is fairly straightforward, but with the downwards movement I don't know what to do.

Hint: If you fix how we go right in each column, then ...

I suspect you can pencil in numbers of routes coming into different nodes in different directions. Possibly something like this, by summing earlier possibilities

which, if correct (corrected by Calvin Lin), might suggest $36$ routes from $T_i$ to $Z$ and $20$ routes from $Z$ to $T_o$. You then take the product of these. The equal numbers on each horizontal line explains Calvin Lin's comments to the original question and this answer: $T_i$ to $Z$ can be done $3 \times 6 \times 2$ ways and $Z$ to $T_o$ $4 \times 5$ ways.
This approach would not work if you were also allowed to move left but still could not go to the same point more than once.

There are 36 routes from $T_i$ to $Z$, and 20 routes from $Z$ to $T_o$.  Note that for your second column top row, there are 3 ways to get to it, not 2. That's the only error that you have  $\quad$ I encourage you to use my hint. Written in your language, for each column of vertices, when there is a path out, show that the sum of numbers leading into any vertex is a constant. (If there is no path out, the sum would also be a constant if we ignore the constraint of having to reach a certain location.) Relate this constant to the number of horizontal rows.

@CalvinLin - Thank you - edited.
